# htaccess server error when removing www from url

Tags: .htaccess, no-www

.htacess error

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.netsentries.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://netsentries/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]





</IfModule>
```

Error only comes when I add this line.

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.netsentries.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://netsentries/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have to add it because my site is not loading with www now. I want to make it load.

Comment: What is the error? What does it say in your error logs?

Comment: Try moving the rewritebase to the above all rewrite-rules. Code looks just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and your htaccess problem will be solved:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # no www
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and if you have problem loading your site with www it is because of loosing www CNAME record from your website's host. You should check the nameservers from "DNS zone editor" of your websites hosting package and adding required records for www like this:

```
NAME:www.yoursite.com.   TTL:14400    TYPE:CNAME    RECORD:yoursite.com.
```

this will cause your website to work in both with and without www.

Answer (score -1):

Try this once

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.netsentries\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://netsentries.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: http_host never contains a slash at the end, but only the domain name. But escaping the dots is a good suggestion.